# C# How to detect whether there is a '/' character?

Tags: c#

I have three IP addresses from serial port in one string. For example the string is like `192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118`. How do we detect the '/' character so that we can split this string into 3 IP address string and put each one into IP1 string, IP2 string and IP3 string?

Comment: You should be able to answer this question on your own, especially after your last question (25 minutes ago) where every answer involved a `string.Split`

Comment: Maybe you should search before asking questions....

Comment: How do you expect to learn if you don't try stuff out and make your own mistakes? This would take all of 5 minutes research to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string arrStr = "192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118";
char[] separator = new char[] { '/' };
string[] strSplitArr = arrStr.Split(separator);

string IP1 = strSplitArr[0];
string IP2 = strSplitArr[1];
string IP3 = strSplitArr[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

`var res = "192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118".Split('/');`

Comment: I like this answer.  Simple and to the point the others are over engineered.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do like that :

```
string sRaw = "192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118";
string[] sParts = new string[]{};

if(sRaw.Contains('/')){
  sParts = sRaw.Split('/');
}
```

But don't forget to use IPAddress for validating IP.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `String.Split('/')` method

Example:

```
var text = "192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118".Split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sData = "192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118";
string[] sIps = null;

if (sData.Contains('/'))
    sIps = sData.split('/');

// sIps[i] contains your data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to avoid getting empty items caused by duplicate/tailing slashes from the input data.

```
var data = "192.168.1.1/192.168.1.12/192.168.1.118";
var result = data.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```